# Netbeans + Glassfish

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

Estou usando o Netbeans 8.0.2 e o Glassfish 4.1.

Toda vez que faço alguma alteração, em qualquer classe do meu projeto, não consigo testá-lo apenas clicando em "Executar Projeto (F6)", como faço em outros projetos que usam o Tomcat.

Sempre tenho que "Cancelar a Implantação" da aplicação, "Interromper" o Glassfish e, só então, "Executar Projeto".

Já venho procurando uma solução há algum tempo, sem sucesso.

Alguém poderia me dar alguma luz?

Comment: Executar o projeto é demorado. Depois de você executar o projeto e conseguir depurar o glassfish uma vez, nas próximas vezes você pode simplesmente "attachar" o depurador ao processo do GlassFish. É muito rápido: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqDebuggingRemote. Outra coisa: recomendo deixar o NetBeans em inglês. A tradução para português além de ser muito ruim vai dificultar encontrar ajuda no google pois os artigos sempre utilizam os termos em inglês.

Comment: Caffé, ajudou muito!!! - Como auxílio deixo também um tutorial mais detalhado, para quem também esteja com a mesma dificuldade: http://www.devmedia.com.br/configuracoes-iniciais-para-um-ambiente-de-desenvolvimento-de-aplicacoes-corporativas-no-java/25889 (7.2. Usando um depurador).